# Keras hyperparameter tuning

Tags: python, keras, scikit-learn, hyperparameters

using this dataset https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/harlfoxem/housesalesprediction?datasetId=128&searchQuery=hyperparameter+tuning&language=Python

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np 
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.wrappers.scikit_learn import KerasRegressor


#Random seed for reproducibiliity
np.random.seed(5)


####DATA PRE-PROCESSING ####
#read the data
data = pd.read_csv('kc_house_data.csv')
#check for missing/null values
print(data.isnull().any())
#create a 'house age' colum that encompasses both date (which doesn't help in predicting price) and the year built
data['date'] = pd.to_datetime(data['date']) #first convert date format 
data["house_age"] = data["date"].dt.year - data['yr_built']

#if 'renovated' is 0, it means not renovated- so to stop confusion, if year renovated is not 0, add 1 to a new 'renovated' column
data['renovated'] = data['yr_renovated'].apply(lambda yr: 0 if yr == 0 else 1)
#Now drop the columns we do not need
data=data.drop('date', axis=1)
data=data.drop('yr_renovated', axis=1)
data=data.drop('yr_built', axis=1)
data.head(5)

print(data)


#Split into test and train
X = data
Y = X['price'].values
X = X.drop('price', axis = 1)
X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = train_test_split (X, Y, test_size = 0.20, random_state=42) 
X_val, X_test, Y_val, Y_test = train_test_split(X_test, Y_test, test_size=0.5) #splitting into validation sets as well - not sure if needed tho


#Scale
standard_scaler = StandardScaler() #Unsure if min max scaler would be more appropriate here? 
X_train= pd.DataFrame(standard_scaler.fit_transform(X_train),columns=X_train.columns)
X_test = pd.DataFrame(standard_scaler.transform(X_test),columns = X_test.columns)
X_val = pd.DataFrame(standard_scaler.transform(X_test),columns = X_val.columns)
#print(X_train.shape, X_val.shape, X_test.shape, Y_train.shape, Y_val.shape, Y_test.shape)


# Use scikit-learn to grid search the batch size and epochs
    
def create_model():
    # create model
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(32, input_dim=19, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
    # Compile model
    model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam' , metrics='mse')
    return model

# create model
model = KerasRegressor(build_fn=create_model, verbose=0)
# define the grid search parameters
batch_size = [5, 10, 20, 40, 60, 80]
epochs = [10, 50, 100]
param_grid = dict(batch_size=batch_size)
grid = GridSearchCV(estimator=model, param_grid=param_grid, n_jobs=-1, cv=3, scoring = 'neg_mean_squared_error')
grid_result = grid.fit(X_train, Y_train)
# summarize results
print("Best: %f using %s" % (grid_result.best_score_, grid_result.best_params_))


param_grid = dict(epochs=epochs)
grid = GridSearchCV(estimator=model, param_grid=param_grid, n_jobs=-1, cv=3, scoring = 'neg_mean_squared_error')
grid_result = grid.fit(X_train, Y_train)
# summarize results
print("Best: %f using %s" % (grid_result.best_score_, grid_result.best_params_))
```

It's just not working for me. What I want to do is create a simple neural network and then finetune the epochs and batch size. But this is just giving me 'acccuracy' as NAN. I'm so confused. Any help appreciated

Current output:

```
Best: -419841571707.859070 using {'batch_size': 5}
Best: -419841571132.739441 using {'epochs': 100}
```

However if i add batch sizes of 1,2,3 etc, it will give that- it always says the best result is the smallest batch size. Is this right?

Comment: You aren't using the correct loss/metrics for a regression task. Try using `loss=mean_squared_error` (see "Regression losses" https://keras.io/api/losses/) and `scoring='neg_mean_squared_error'` in the GridSearchCV (see https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html#scoring-parameter).

Comment: Thanks i tried this but unfortunately it still doesnt work @hbgoddard i think there is more wrong with my code :(

Comment: Did you change the model's `metrics` too? It would help if you edited your question with your updated code and the exact error message/bad output you're getting.

Comment: Hi, i have updated the code above now. Thank you so much for replying. My current output: Best: -419841571707.859070 using {'batch_size': 5} Best: -419841571132.739441 using {'epochs': 100}

However if i add batch sizes of 1,2,3 etc, it will give that- it always says the best result is the smallest batch size. Is this right?

Comment: Those results indicate very poor performance, and I trust them because your model architecture is far too small. Try adding more and larger layers to your model and see where that takes you. Additionally, you can perform your grid search on all parameter options at the same time (`param_grid = dict(batch_size=batch_size, epochs=epochs)`) and it will find the best combination.